# TTF font to icon doesn't work in listview android

Tags: android, listview, truetype

I have a ttf file containing weather icons. I want to use this fonts to create weather icons in a listview for daily temp. I have set it up well and I am getting icon also in listview but not at everywhere only one of the eight listview items. Plus as I scroll up and down it refreshes to just one place and not everywhere. I am posting the getview method for my list view where I am setting all the data.

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_whether_list_style, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.weatherIcon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weather_iconT);
            holder.maxTemp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.max_temp);
            holder.minTemp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.min_temp);
            holder.dayName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else  holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        Daily daily = dailyTest.get(position);
        holder.description.setText(daily.getDescription());
        holder.dayName.setText(daily.getFormattedTime());

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Weather&Time.ttf" );
        holder.weatherIcon.setTypeface(typeface);
        holder.weatherIcon.setText(daily.getWeatherIconString());


        //for two digit temp format.. adding 0 for single digits.
        int maxtemp = (daily.getMaxTemp()-32)*5/9;
        if(maxtemp<10){
            holder.maxTemp.setText("0"+ maxtemp);
        } else holder.maxTemp.setText(""+ maxtemp);

        int mintemp = (daily.getMinTemp()-32)*5/9;
        if(mintemp<10) {
            holder.minTemp.setText("0"+ mintemp);

        } else holder.minTemp.setText(""+ mintemp);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: If the font is an "icon font", like fontello or fontastic, you need to refer the correct Unicode characters.

Comment: unicode is correct but the problem is it only renders in two of the list view items outof 8

Comment: Do you use Android N Dev-Preview?

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your Viewholder class code also.

If you have mentioned static Textview, remove static keyword from them.

Also you can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for more info

Comment: no static fields in viewholder. and the doc is for displaying bitmaps.. I am not rendering bitmap here.. its just fonts converted to icons in a text view..

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing context to createFromAsset fonts,pass context to createFromAsset and try this code.

```
 if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_whether_list_style, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.weatherIcon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weather_iconT);
            holder.maxTemp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.max_temp);
            holder.minTemp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.min_temp);
            holder.dayName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else  holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        Daily daily = dailyTest.get(position);
        holder.description.setText(daily.getDescription());
        holder.dayName.setText(daily.getFormattedTime());

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Weather&Time.ttf" );
        holder.weatherIcon.setTypeface(typeface);
        holder.weatherIcon.setText(daily.getWeatherIconString());


        //for two digit temp format.. adding 0 for single digits.
        int maxtemp = (daily.getMaxTemp()-32)*5/9;
        if(maxtemp<10){
            holder.maxTemp.setText("0"+ maxtemp);
        } else holder.maxTemp.setText(""+ maxtemp);

        int mintemp = (daily.getMinTemp()-32)*5/9;
        if(mintemp<10) {
            holder.minTemp.setText("0"+ mintemp);

        } else holder.minTemp.setText(""+ mintemp);


        return convertView;
    }
```